# Debug Console throws syntax error instead of showing exception message

Tags: python, exception, visual-studio-code

I keep on getting very strange behavior when I execute lines of code in the the DEBUG CONSOLE: I get a syntax error, instead of the actual message of the exception.  Here is a very simple example of a code snippet, that intentionally has an error in it:

```
import pandas as pd

# this is incorrect, as it should be "data = {'values': [1]}"
data = {'values': 1}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

If I run this with the debugger, I get the expected ValueError ("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"). However, if I run this in the DEBUG CONSOLE, I get a syntax error instead of the message from the exception:

```
SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 4, 'df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)'))
```

Any ideas? I get this all the time, not just for pandas. This behavior makes is really hard to debug code, because of the actual error message, I just get this SyntaxError.

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue here and on [our github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2949). **Summary**: The assignment seems to be obfuscating the error in the debug console, and a workaround would be to not assign the construction of the object to a variable within the debug console window. `m = pd.DataFrame(data=data)` gives the SyntaxError, but `pd.DataFrame(data=data)` gives the desired ValueError. Our team will look into it further.